# cakephp plugin for google login (cakephp 2.x)?

Tags: cakephp, plugins, google-signin

I started to configure google login on my new application.

but i keep getting the following error:

`Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_grant'`

this is where google redirects it 
`mydomain/users/googleLogin?code=4/eNLkWLNm4ywTLcPDN4obcH_PZIRj.wsIKrDgwdCseXE-sT2ZLcbSD1t1_iAI`

if I removed the `?` mark from the url this works fine. Please help me with this.

Comment: Thanks. I use the Google_client.php with other source code which use Google_OAuth2